Woocommerce sidebar overrides filters plugin styles
I am developing an ecommerce website with Astra theme and Woocommerce. Whatever filters plugin I use (e.g. Ajax Products Filter https://berocket.com/woocommerce-ajax-products-filter/?refer_id=25, YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-product-filter/) the plugin's styles seem to get overwritten when I include the plugin into the woocommerce sidebar (Appearance > Widgets > WooCommerce Sidebar). Is there a way to prevent this and have nicely styled filters like in the demos shown on the filters' pages? I would prefer avoiding modifying the CSS styles by hand as this would be extremely inefficient. Below is an example of how the filters look like on the demo page:
https://woocommerce-products-filter.berocket.com/shop/?_gl=1
Here, instead, the ugly looking filters on my page after I modified the CSS as much as I could:
https://acro-metric.com/product-category/measurement/pressure/pressure-gauges/
Below are screenshots of how they look without modifying the CSS:


The same thing happens with any plugin.
If your answer includes anything related to php I would like you to know that I can't code in php so please be kind with your explanations :) Thank you for your help!

Check priority of scripts. Load theme like Storefront and check if its overwritten. In case its not prob the style overwrite is comming from the theme ? I have lots of websites using woo ajax filter and all work properly.
